# Need to integrate automation anywhere using Mule esb

Tags: mule, automationanywhere, mulesoft

I have a requirement, I am having access to automation anywhere Control room? I want to understand how to retrieve the metadata/data from control room.. Is there any Api available? How to communicate? I am planning to do integration via Mule esb …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to AA support, you can find all the information about Control Room 11 APIs [here](https://support.automationanywhere.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003731313-Control-Room-APIs).

> Control Room offers the following APIs:
>
> - Authentication
> - Bot Login Credentials
> - Bot Deployment
> - Export and Import Bots for Bot Lifecycle Management
> - Export Import Workload Management Configuration
> - Get list of all queues
> - Get list of all work items in a given queue
> - Insert work item data to a given queue